# How to check the integrity of a signed C# DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, certificate, x509certificate

I have a signed C# Dll that I want to test for authenticity and file integrity.
What I did so far is getting the certificate and calling the Verify method that is found on that certificate:

```
public ValidatorResult CheckDll()
{
    X509Certificate cert = null;
    try
    {
       cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(dllFilepath);
    }
    catch (CryptographicException)
    {
       return new ValidatorResult(ValidatorResult.DllStatus.INVALID_SIGNATURE);
    }

    if (cert == null || !ValidateCertificate(cert))
    {
       return new ValidatorResult(ValidatorResult.DllStatus.INVALID_SIGNATURE);
    }
}   

private bool ValidateCertificate(X509Certificate cert)
{
    var chain = new X509Chain();

    /* Do a chain verification */
    var primaryCert = new X509Certificate2(cert.GetRawCertData());
    if (!chain.Build(primaryCert))
       return false;

    /* Call The Verify method on the newer X509Certificate2 class */
    if (!primaryCert.Verify())
       return false;

    return true;
}
```

I could be wrong, so please correct me but from what I've seen on the internet the Verify() method only check the validity of the certificate. I also need to check the integrity of the file.

I did a small test using "Resource Hacker" tool were I loaded the dll and changed the company name. This modified dll passed the code above.

How should I change the code so that I can check if the file was modified?

Thank you.

Comment: All primaryCert.Verify() does is call Build() on a default options X509Chain.  So your two if blocks are functionally repeats of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to verify the DLL

```
[DllImport("mscoree.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx(
        string wszFilePath, bool fForceVerification, ref bool pfWasVerified);    

bool pfWasVerified = false;
if (!StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx("path...to...DLL", true, ref pfWasVerified))
{           
    // it's a modified DLL file!   
}
```

Comment: It's strange because I was able to pass as a "valid dll" using the code above with a modified dll.

Comment: Yes, Verify Performs a X.509 chain validation using basic validation policy. So it only checks if the certificate is Valid not if the file is valid, sorry. So you get no check at all with Verify

Comment: @Daniel I've updated it with a solution, there is no managed way to do this, you have to P/Invoke StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx